# How to generate the DDL from an existing Postgres Database?

Tags: postgresql, docker, export, schema, ddl

How can I export my DB schema (without data dump) as a *SQL* file with the **DDL** so I can  re-create the DB without additional tools?

Also, I need the DDL to generate a Visual Paradigm Entity-Relationship diagram with reverse diagram generation.

Comment: Please do not put "solved" into the title. Accept the answer instead.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer

Comment: Yes, you can. You might need to wait a bit though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [VP Community forums](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/reverse-ddl.jsp#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Tools%20%3E%20Database%20%3E%20Reverse,the%20ERD%20for%20you%20automatically.) and I want to share it with you :)

```
pg_dump -U [USER] -h [HOST] -p [PORT]  --schema-only [DATABASE_NAME] > [TARGET_PATH]
```

**Example:**

```
pg_dump -U root -h localhost -p 5432  --schema-only my_db > ~/db_schema_ddl.sql
```

**Or if you are using docker:**

```
docker exec -i [CONTAINER_ID] pg_dump -U [USER]  --schema-only DATABASE_NAME > [TARGET_PATH]
```